# Powershell Reg exp and replace a part of it

Tags: powershell

I have a line in a file like 
3875-01-12T04:30:00Z
I wanna replace T***Z string to NULL.

Please not that the string between T and Z can be diferent, so I need to get the string inside T and Z and replace it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $subject -creplace 'T[\d:.]*Z', ''
```

should do. I added the dot in case you encounter times that are more precise than seconds.

If you want to make sure that the `T...Z` is only deleted if it follows a `yyyy-mm-dd` string, then use

```
$result = $subject -creplace '(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T[\d:.]*Z', ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you:

```
'3875-01-12T04:30:00Z' -replace 'T(.+)Z$'
```

If you want to keep 'TZ':

```
'3875-01-12T04:30:00Z' -replace 'T(.+)Z$','TZ'
```